Error System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: No signature message parts were specified for messages with the '' action
Description: A 3rd party application based on C# connects with our Java application. The application was recently migrated to Java 11 from Java 8 and uses Apache CXF version 3.6.1. The error started occurring after the migration to Java 11.
Below is the WSS4J configuration in xml format. Earlier in java 8 cxf version 2.3.3 was used and has been upgraded to 3.6.1.
<bean id="signEncryptInInterceptor"
class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
<constructor-arg>
    <map>
        <entry key="action" value="Signature Encrypt" />
        <entry key="projectProperties" value-ref="projectProperties" />
        <entry key="signaturePropRefId" value="projectProperties" />
        <entry key="decryptionPropRefId" value="projectProperties" />
        <entry key="passwordCallbackRef" value-ref="pwdCallback" />
    </map>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="signEncryptOutInterceptor"
class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">
<constructor-arg>
    <map>
        <entry key="action" value="Signature Encrypt" />
        <entry key="projectProperties" value-ref="projectProperties" />
        <entry key="signaturePropRefId" value="projectProperties" />
        <entry key="encryptionPropRefId" value="projectProperties" />
        <entry key="user" value="projectServicekey" />
        <entry key="encryptionUser" value="projectclientkey" />
        <entry key="passwordCallbackRef" value-ref="pwdCallback" />
        <entry key="encryptionParts"
            value="{Element}{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}Signature;{Content}{http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Body" />
        <entry key="encryptionSymAlgorithm"
            value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
        <entry key="signatureParts"
            value="{Element}{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}Action; {Element}{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}MessageID; />
    </map>
</constructor-arg>

Please note that the project-specific tags have been renamed.
Below are the changes tried:
1.Included signatureParts property in the signEncryptOutInterceptor bean.
2.Tried renaming signaturePropRefId from existing SignaturePropRefId as per the official WSS4J documentation https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/config.html Earlier it was SignaturePropRefId.
Please help to resolve the issue
